# Bounding the entries of a weight vector

Tags: algorithm

Let `v = (v(1), ..., v(n))` be a vector of positive reals such that `v(1) + ... + v(n) = 1`. Let `l > 0` such that `1/l ≤ n` and assume that `v(k) > l` for some `k`.

Consider the following algorithm:

1. Put `v(k) = l` for every `k` such that `v(k) > l`.
2. Normalise `v`, that is, put `v = v / (v(1) + ... + v(n))`.

It's easy to see that the repeated application of this algorithm to `v` converges to some vector `w` such that `w(k) ≤ l` for every `k` and `w(1) + ... w(k) = 1`. My goal is to find a fast algorithm that computes the exact value of `w`.

An idea is replacing every entry of `v` that is bigger than `l` by `l` and then normalising the rest of the entries. This leads to the following algorithm:

1. Let `I = (i(1), ..., i(m))` be the list of indexes such that `v(k) > l` if and only if `k` belongs to `I` and `J = (j(1), ..., j(n-m))` be its complement, that is, the list of indexes such that `v(k) ≥ l` if and only if `k` belongs to `J`.
2. Put `v(i(k)) = l` for every `1 ≤ k ≤ m`.
3. Put `v = (1 - m * l) * v(j(k)) / (v(j(1)) + ... + v(j(k)))` for every `1 ≤ k ≤ n-m`.

The problem is that there may exist some `k` such that `v(k) < l` before applying the algorithm and `v(k) > l` after applying it. So, it's still necessary to apply it repeatedly. Nevertheless, it converges to `w` in at most `n` steps.

Applying the previous algorithm repeatedly is equivalent to replacing the `m` largest entries of `v` by `l` and then normalising the rest of the entries, for certain choice of `m`. Is there a fast way to find the value of `m` or the vector `w`, possibly in linear time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut instinct (often wrong!) is that the best you can do it in is `O(n log n)` time. To do it in `O(n log n)` time:

1. Put the array in ascending order (time complexity `O(n log n)` - e.g. MergeSort)
2. Make an array of cumulative totals (This requires traversing the array once, so `O(n)` time complexity.)
3. For every `m`, it is now easy to decide in *constant time* whether the array obtained by replacing the largest `m` numbers by `1` and normalizing is what you want. (The sum of all numbers will be one of the cumulative totals plus `m`, so you just need to check the value of the `(m+1)`-th largest value divided by that total. Therefore to find `m` at this stage requires a linear search, again `O(n)`.

Therefore the overall time complexity of this algorithm is `o(n log n)`.